# Copy file to folder from file path

Tags: batch-file

I  have a notepad file mentioning file path, from these file paths I want to copy files to a folder but files  with same name get overwrite how can I rename these same file name using batch code so all files get copied to folder??

Code I have written

```
@echo off
SET src=c:\link.txt
set dest=c:\files 
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (%link%) DO COPY "%%a" "%dest%\%%~nxa" /-Y
pause
```

Any help to improve this ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. It checks each individual file and keeps appending numbers until a unique name is determined.

The below script would preserve the original name if it doesn't exist in `dest` but in future calls it would append a sequential number. For example:

- First call: `MyFile.txt`
- Second call: `MyFile-2.txt`
- Third call: `MyFile-3.txt`

This doesn't consider any timestamps, rather just keeps incrementing a number until the first available (non-used) filename is determined.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

REM Source file which contains a list of full file names.
REM This filename should _not_ be in quotes.
SET src=c:\link.txt

REM Directory to copy the files to.
REM This should _not_ be in quotes.
REM Entire declaration wrapped in quotes to prevent accidental spaces on the end.
set "dest=c:\files"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a IN ("%src%") DO (
    ECHO Processing: %%a
    CALL :DoCopy "%%a" 0
)
pause

ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF


:DoCopy
REM First parameter is the file name.
REM Second parameter is the number to append on matches.
SET /A Append=%~2+1

SET FileToCheck="%dest%\%~nx1"
IF NOT "%Append%"=="1" (
    REM If we get here a duplicate name exists.
    REM Append the number to the end.
    SET FileToCheck="%dest%\%~n1-%Append%%~x1"
)

IF NOT EXIST %FileToCheck% (
    REM Does not exist, copy it.
    COPY "%~1" %FileToCheck% /-Y
    GOTO :EOF
) ELSE (
    REM File does exist.
    REM Keep going until we have a unique value.
    CALL :DoCopy "%~1" %Append%
    GOTO :EOF
)
```

Comment: Well there is some problem in this code,files are not copying in folder.I am kind of rookie in this could you help me to sort this out??

Comment: @geeko - Worked for me as is. I updated the answer a bit with some instructions and to have it display the files as they process. See what this gives you.

Comment: I can't see a definition of the system variable `link`. So that `... %%a IN ("%link%") DO ...` should be `... %%a IN ("%src%") DO ...` And  use `CALL :DoCopy "%%~a" 0` to assure use of right filename regardless it appear with or without surrounding double quotes in the _source file_ `c:\link.txt`

Comment: @geeko - I have applied the fix noted by JosefZ. It should work as posted now.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner I have run code but file path specified not found error I am getting for each file ,I have made changes as mentioned by you.What am I missing??

Comment: @geeko - As long as your file `c:\link.txt` has a single _full_ file path per line in it, the script should work. Do you get the messages on your screen which say `Processing: [file name]`?

Comment: @JasonFaulkner Iam getting this msg Processing: [file name] The System  cannot find path specified .Files in notepad  are in this format C:\Users\admin\AppData\LocalLow\(filename 1)
            C:\Users\admin\AppData\LocalLow\(filename 2)
            C:\Users\admin\AppData\LocalLow\(filename 3)

Comment: @geeko - As long as the full path (`C:\Users\admin\AppData\LocalLow(filename 1)`) is valid, it should work. You can try removing the `@echo off` line and see what what the command is which produces the error.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner Got the problem.Its working now.Space after dest=c:files making it not to work.Thanks for your prompt help.

Comment: @geeko - You can avoid this by wrapping your entire `SET` statement in quotes. I updated the answer to reflect this.